How to customize the error shown in stripe hosted checkout page?
I use stripe hosted checkout page for payments.  How to show user-friendly message instead of the stripe one?
For example, below is the error message shown to the user. I'd like to customize the message.
error message:
Non-INR transactions in India should have shipping/billing address outside India. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports


I do not think you can customize this error messages on a Stripe Hosted Checkout integration, https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/quickstart. I think reaching out to their support team to share your feedback would be helpful.

stripe support response: Hello, unfortunately we don't have a way to customize Checkout error messages at the moment. I can put in a feature request for showing your own message, but for now you'd need to build your own Elements page to take payments through.
my current workaround is to send user an email when this happens.
